# How to invalidate session on logout in Spring

Tags: spring-security

I have a web application where I use spring security. I have a problem logging out because my application remembers the last page after logging out. What I want is once the user logs out should not be able go back.

My `application-config` snippet :

```
<security:logout logout-url="/logout.do"
    invalidate-session="true" 
    logout-success-url="/logoutSuccess.do" />
```

Comment: Do you mean it should clear the navigation history of the client browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    HttpServletRequest.getSession(false).invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard logout filter will invalidate the current HTTPSession, if your user has a cached version of one of your protected pages there isn't much you can do about that however even if they return to that page they will not be able to use it to make any further requests to your application until they obtain another valid session.